# How to compare array with an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a data like below

```
var array = [
  {'id':'2', 'key':'test1', 'value':'val1'},
  {'id':'2','key':'test2','value':'val2'}
]
```

I have an object which is the result of edited data of the above array

```
 var object = {'test1':'newval1','test2':'newval2'}
```

Now i need to compare my 'object' with 'array' and append id to it and prepare it as

```
var finalArray = [
  {'id':'2','key':'test1','value':'newval1'},
  {'id':'2','key':'test2','value':'newval2'}
]
```

To implement this I tried this

```
for(var i = 0;i < array.length;i++) {
        for (var key in object) {
            if(array[i].key == key) {
                this.toUpdateData['key'] = array[i].key;
                this.toUpdateData['value'] = object[key];
                this.toUpdateData['id'] = array[i].id;
                this.finalArray.push(this.toUpdateData);
                delete this.data[key];
            }
       }
```

But this resulting in a duplicate values.I did wrong can anyone oplease help me.Thanks.
        }

Therefore I want my final array like

```
var finalArray = [
  {'id':'2','key':'test1','value':'newval1'},
  {'id':'2','key':'test2','value':'newval2'}
]
```

Comment: Covert the object to it's array form and write a function that can compare two arrays.

Comment: The questions you are asking are not related to angular or any other framework. Please use only the relevant tags

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: Your final output doesnt make sense. Where did the values from first array go? Why newval2 is in test2 but is in test1 in final array?

Comment: Do you mean your array's second object has `key` `test2` but look like a typo since you have `test1`?

Comment: yes,I edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
You can do it in just one loop since you mentioned that `object` is anyways obtained from the `array`. Iterate the array and get the array element's `key` Use that key to read from object and update array element with that read value.

```js
var array = [{'id':'2','key':'test1','value':'val1'},{'id':'2','key':'test2','value':'val2'}];
var object = {'test1':'newval1','test2':'newval2'};

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
   var key = array[i].key;
   array[i].value = object[key];
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array and check if the key exist in the update object. Then update the value property.

```js
var array = [{ id: '2', key: 'test1', value: 'val1' }, { id: '2', key: 'test2', value: 'val2' }],
  object = { test1: 'newval1', test2: 'newval2' };
  
array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.key in object) {
        a.value = object[a.key];
    }
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```